# LOGIC of Converting a "char" into an "int" in C

Tags: c, char, int, logic, atoi

everyone!

please help me understand the following problem...
So i will have a STRING-type input of a note, looks like "A5" or "G#2" or "Cb4" etc. And i need to extract an octave index, which is the last digit "5" or "2" or "4"... And after exctraction i need it as an int-type.

So I did this:

```
string note = get_string("Input: ");
int octave = atoi(note[strlen(note) - 1]);
printf("your octave is %i \n", octave);
```

But it gave me an error **"error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type 'const char *'; take the address with & [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]"**

Then I tryied to throug away the math from the function, and did this:

```
int extnum = strlen(note) - 1;
int octave = atoi(note[extnum]);
```

It didn't work as well. So i did my reserch on atoi function and i don't get it...

1. ATOI expects a string (CHECK)
2. Converts it to an interger, not the ASCII meanning (CHECK)
3. Library for atoi function (CHECK)

What I am doing in basically asking "take n-th character of that string and make it an int".

After googling for some time a found an other code example where a guy uses atoi with this symbol '&'. **So i did this**:

```
int octave = atoi(&note[strlen(note) - 1]);
```

And IT WORKED! But I can't understand WHY it worked with the & symbol and didnt work without it....Cause it always worked without it! There was a million times i was giving a single-character string like '5' or so ond just used atoi and it worked perfectly...

**Plesase help me, why in this case it acts so weird?**

Comment: C does not have a native `string` type. So what is string?

Comment: `'5'` is *not* a "string". `"5"` is a "string".

Comment: So that magic `&` thing isn't just some random symbol, it's the C address-of operator, which gives you a pointer to something.  And strings in C are very often manipulated using pointers to characters.  So to understand what's going on here, you're going to have to learn more about strings and pointers in C.  Also you need to think about the distinction between characters and strings: a character is one single character, while a string is an array of zero or more characters.

Comment: Specifically, `note` and `note + strlen(note) - 1` could be said to be a "string" (in a certain way of speaking); `note[strlen(note) - 1]` is a single `char`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `atoi` takes a pointer to a character array as the input parameter (`const char*`). When you call `note[strlen(note) - 1]` this is a single character (`char`), in order to make `atoi` work you need to provide the pointer. You do that by adding `&` as you've done. This then works, because right after that single digit there is a null character `\0` that terminates the string - because your original string was null-terminated.

Note however that doing something like this would not be a good idea:

```
char a = '7';
int b = atoi(&a);
```

as there is no way to be sure what the next byte in memory is (following the byte that belongs to `a`), but the function will try to read it anyway, which can lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

C does not have a native string type. Strings are usually represented as char array or a pointer to char.

Assuming that `string` is just a typedef to `char *`.

if `note` is an array of chars, `note[strlen(note)-1]` is just the last character. Since `atoi` expects a pointer to char (which has to be null-terminated) you have to pass the address of the char and not the value.

The task to convert one char digit to int could also be solved easier:

```
int octave = note[strlen(note) - 1] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The last character is... well a character! not a string. So by adding the `&` sign, you made it a pointer to character (`char*`)!

You can also try this code:

```
char a = '5';
int b = a - '0';
```

Gives you ASCII code of `5` minus ASCII code of `0`

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=atoi&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html), the signature of `atoi` is: `int atoi(const char *nptr);`. So, you need to pass the address of a `char`.

When you do this: `atoi(note[strlen(note) - 1])` you pass the `char` itself. Thus, invoking [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

When you use the `&`, you are passing what the function expects - the address. Hence, that works.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` excepts a string (a pointer to character), not a single character.

However, you should never use `atoi` since that function has bad error handling. The function [`strtol`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) is 100% equivalent but safer.

You need to do this in two steps:

1. Find the first digit in the string.
2. From there, convert it to integer by calling `strtol`.

1) can is solved by looping through the string, checking if every item is a digit by calling `isdigit` from ctype.h. Simultaneously, check for the end of the string, the null terminator `\0`. When you find the first digit, save a pointer to that address.

2) is solved by passing the saved pointer to `strtol`, such as `result = strtol(pointer, NULL, 10);`.